# How can i show an image from a database in mysql(blob), to an "Image" control in a web page

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web

I'm trying to make a test website where i can upload an image and some text in a database and retrieve the image in a "preview" Image control.
I already managed to store these elements as varchar and blob(MEDIUMBLOB).(MySql)

However i'm having trouble trying to show the stored image in the Image control.

here's the code:

```
MySqlConnection conn;
MySqlCommand comand;
String queryStr;
MySqlDataAdapter daa;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    int fileSize = postedFile.ContentLength;
    try
    {
        if (fileExtension.ToLower()==".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            AgregarCiudad();//add city method in spanish
            Response.Write("Exito");
            MostrarImagen();//show image method also in spanish lol
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Solo Imagenes .jpg o .png de 15 megabites o menos.");
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fFileNotFound)
    {
        //log the exception the specified fFileNotFound variable has to be put in a string, label or response.
        Response.Write("Error." + fFileNotFound.Message);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }
}
private void AgregarCiudad()
{
    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
    conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";
    queryStr = "INSERT INTO testingdb.country (Relation, Name, ImageStock)" +
        "VALUES(?Relation, ?Name, ?ImageStock)";
    comand = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Relation", TextBox1.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Name", TextBox2.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ImageStock", FileUpload1);

    comand.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close();
}
```

as you can see here, i don't know what else to do now, what could be done to make this method to show the recently stored image in the Image control (Image1)?

```
private void MostrarImagen()
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT ImageStock FROM testingdb.country WHERE 
Name ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
    comand = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    reader = comand.ExecuteReader();
    Image1.ImageUrl = selectQuery;
    conn.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am supposing that you are receiving the blob data from the database. After that try something like this:

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(your blob);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: what do you mean by (your blob)? what could i put there?

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-BLOB-Images-from-MySql-Database-in-ASPNet-C-and-VBNet.aspx

This might help you